# Is it possible to use environment variables in next.js rewrites?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am developing my app with next.js frontend and express.js backend by simply running the relevant dev severs in the terminal. However, I want to run production using Docker, where the ip of my API would be the name of the container instead of localhost. I would also like to use different ports for dev and production.

During the development, I just had a hardcoded rewrites, like this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `http://localhost:5000/api/:path*`,
      },
      {
        source: "/auth/:path*",
        destination: `http://localhost:5000/auth/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and it worked just fine. However, when I started moving towards production I wanted to base the destination URL based on environment variables, so in dev environment, the destination for /api would be http://localhost:5000/api and in production environment it would be http://api:5100/api (referencing the api Docker container).

After some time of trying to figure out why this does not work, I bumped into this GitHub issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21888
It basically says that you cannot use environment variables in the next.config.js.

So, is there a different way to have an environment-dependent rewrites, since this seem not to be an option?

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.bitsrc.io/setting-up-next-js-url-rewrites-with-netlify-254e1007d74d

Answer (score 2):

Please see if you can solve this case with [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware). Unlike next.config.js, middleware picks up runtime environment variables.

```js
// middleware.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/api/:path*", "/auth/:path*"],
};

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.rewrite(
    new URL(
      `${process.env.API_HOST}${request.nextUrl.pathname}${request.nextUrl.search}`
    ),
    { request }
  );
}
```

Comment: The NextResponse rewrite function actually takes a string as the first argument, so the URL constructor should be removed.

Comment: @rabbibillclinton its type is: `NextResponse<Body = unknown>.rewrite(destination: string | NextURL | URL, init?: MiddlewareResponseInit | undefined): NextResponse<unknown>` - so it can be passed a URL or a string.